# Run AngularJS Tutorial with VSCode

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

I was hoping to try VSCode on the AngularJS tutorial, say [step 1](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01), and get debugging and building working.

I was able to get it running, but it's a bit of a hack and VSCode doesn't like it.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
// List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.  
// ONLY "node" and "mono" are supported, change "type" to switch.
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch app.js",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "app\\js\\app.js",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": "run.bat",
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": { }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858
    }
]
```

}

I get an "Error Connection failed" even though it is actually running in a separate command prompt window.

Is there a way to for VSCode to debug a simple application like this that only uses package.json start like this:

```
"start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000"
```

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code supports only Node and Mono debugging, it does not support debugging client JavaScript in the browser.

If you want debug Javascript in the browser, use the browser tools. If you want try out node.js debugging support in VSCode. Start with a sample node.js or [express](http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html) app, then follow the direction in [Visual Studio Code website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging) on setting up debugging.

If you would like to see Visual Studio Code supporting debugging, you can vote it up in [user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7768992-client-script-debugging).